# Appium installed build is showing error "Unable to perform selected action because permissions were not granted"

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, appium, android-sdk-tools

"Unable to perform selected action because permissions were not granted" error is showing in facebook login when i am trying to facebook login through Appium installed build. But this error is not showing when i am performing same action on Prelaunch build getting from developer or Playstore.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is occuring because of keystore problem. when i am installing build through appium in mobile device than it is taking my system default keystore which was different sign apk keystore. because of this facebook permision issue is occurring.

Add following line in appium program

capabilities.setCapability("useKeystore", "true");      capabilities.setCapability("keystorePath","C:/Users/5521/.android/debug.keystore");

This Code will false the default.ketstore & enable User Keystore.